# How to find the arbitrary direction of waves in a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, mean

I have a 2D data, `M`, something similar to the result of this code:

```
xv = 1:.2:10;
yv = 1:.2:5;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(xv, yv);
M = sin(X - 4 * Y) + 0.5 * rand(size(X));
figure;
imagesc(xv, yv, M)
```

`M` shows a periodic variation in the plane. I want to find the direction of this wave.

My approach would be to use `circshift` with a linearly increasing shifts per column of the data, and adjust the shifts until the waves align. But I don't have a good mathematical definition for the best alignment.

Is there any alternative method to define and find the direction of the waves?

[image: M]

Comment: This would benefit from [edit]ing in a [mcve], your image shows your end-goal application, but an example for, say, a 5*5 matrix would be much easier to build on.

Comment: @Wolfie I added a minimal example.

Comment: What would your expected output be? Let's say you averaged along 45 degrees or 60 degrees? Without that it's hard to validate that any proposed solution is working as desired. Your example is still quite large to do any manual calculations for validation in this vein... You suggest an approach - does this not work?

Comment: @Wolfie my suggested approach does work, but it is too manual. Especially, as you mentioned, 45 or 60?! I don't have any mathematical method to evaluate the direction. Any suggestion for that would be appreciated.

Comment: I think my point is, how do you define the angle through a matrix, when that angle isn't a multiple of 45 degrees? It is trivial when it's a multiple of 90, fairly understandable for the 45 degrees between (along diagonals), but for arbitrary angles like you've requested do you want to include elements in multiple calculations or should there be no overlap? How do you define how many averages you should be calculating when you don't have a column/row count because you cut across multiple? Without an expected output example this brief is too broad...

Comment: I think the only sensible way to define the "angle" for the problem is the number of elements to offset by from one row to the next. Which makes `circshift` an extremely direct implementation of the solution. The burden on this question is really to 1) provide a working example of what you have tried and 2) to identify what is "inconvenient" about this solution in the sense that an answer could provide a "more convenient" solution.

Comment: @erfan You can easily find the direction by finding the maximal nonzero 2d frequency if you plot the absolute values of the 2d fourier transform of your picture.

Comment: Look into the Radon transform. It computes your projection at many different angles, then you can simply select the angle at which your contrast is highest.

Comment: Thank you all for clearing the case for me. Now I understand what I should have asked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do so is just use `imrotate` and then use the normal mean. Here I wrote a small script that by brute force iterates over angles and tries to find the right one by maximizing the tv norm of this mean vector:

```
xv = 1:.2:10;
yv = 1:.2:5;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(xv, yv);
M = sin(X - 4 * Y) + 0.5 * rand(size(X));
imagesc(xv, yv, M)

offset = -min(M(:))+1;
angles = 0:1:180; % use any step size you want
tv = zeros(size(angles));
for k = 1:numel(angles)
    % use offset to ensure we can set all artificial zeros to NaN
     imr = imrotate(M +  offset, angles(k));
     imr(imr==0) = NaN;
     imr = imr - offset;
     % measure tv norm of the mean vector
     mean_vector = nanmean(imr, 1);
     tv(k) = mean(abs(diff(mean_vector(~isnan(mean_vector)))));

     subplot(2,2,1);
     imagesc(xv, yv, imr)
     subplot(2,2,2);
     plot(mean_vector);
     subplot(2,2,3);
     plot(angles(1:k), tv(1:k),'-r')
     ylim([0, 1])
     drawnow
end

% find angle with maximal tv norm of means
[~, k] = max(tv);
angle = angles(k);
IMR = imrotate(M, angle);
imagesc(xv, yv, IMR);
subplot(2,2,4);
plot(nanmean(IMR));
```

Comment: BTW: This is really basically the brute force method of what CrisLuengo suggested, and we measure the contrast using the tv norm.

Answer (score 1):

Would a convolution be useful? For this specific case,

```
size = 10;
a = -4; % y=-4x, direction
x = repmat([-size:1:size],2*size+1,1);
y = x';
d = 1-abs(a*x-y)/sqrt(a^2+1);
d(d<0.293)=0;
d2 = sum(d,1);
d(:,d2==0) = [];
d = d/sum(d2);
LM = conv2(M,d,'valid');
LM = [0,0,0,LM,0,0,0];
```

giving you 46 means on the direction `y=-4x`, corresponding to the 46 gridpoints on `y=3`. The zero-tapping borders are not valid and thus set to 0.

But that will not be good for those with angles close to 45 degrees.

I could also imagine using interpolation, if the coordinates of some sample points on each line are saved to the one column of matrices `xq` and `yq`, then this would work

```
V = interp2(X,Y,M,xq,yq);
LM = mean(V,1);
```

Hope that would help.